# Can I import personal electronics from India to Bangladesh while traveling?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, import-taxes, bangladesh

I am from Bangladesh and I am planning a trip to India. I also have a plan to buy an iPhone when I am in India, as the price in Bangladesh is higher than in India.

Now, my questions are: can I get the tax refund from the Indian airport, and do I have to pay import duty in Bangladesh for a personal use phone?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90861/can-i-import-electronics-from-india-to-bangladesh-while-traveling?rq=1